# Disable the fields based on the groups

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to disable the fields based on the user group.

Example:

```
1. Group1 disable Field 1 and Field 2
2. Group2 disable Field 3 and Field 4
3. Group3 disable all the fields.
```

Answer (score 1):

By default Sharepoint isn’t providing column-level security for a reason: performance.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/g/archive/2009/01/22/column-level-security-in-sharepoint.aspx

Few workaround you can try:

3rd Party Tools:
https://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-column-level-security.aspx

Free tools on Codeplex

The first is SPViewPermissionSetting (Powered by Laurent Cotton Aka Suchii - Bewise) http://spviewpermission.codeplex.com/ that allows you to choose what groups have access to specific views

The second is SPListDisplaySetting (Powered by Laurent Cotton Aka Suchii - Bewise) http://splistdisplaysetting.codeplex.com/ that allows you to select the columns that show up in the for new, display, and edit and to choose the group…

There are a few more on the site like OfficeToolbox.SharePoint.Lists v1.0 that only allow you to lock down the column and not choose to allow groups to have different access. http://officetoolbox.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I cant use third party tool. Is there any way to do with java script or other options?

Comment: you can check the codeplex options and doing with javascript would be tricky and not recommended way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) JQuery library to hide fields in forms. `GetGroupCollectionFromUser` returns the collection of groups a user is associated with. Following example demonstrates how to hide a text field based on current user's group:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Shared%20Documents/JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/Shared%20Documents/JS/jquery.SPServices-0.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
    userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
    async: false,
       completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
       var xml = xData.responseXML.xml;
       if (xml.search('Test Group') != -1)
  {
         var feedbackField = $("input[title=Feedback]");
         feedbackField.parent().parent().parent().hide();       
  }
     }
  });
});
</script>
```

Source: http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2011/09/hide-sharepoint-list-field-based-on.html

Comment: Hi Nadeem, Thank you for your guidance. I have download the JS files (jquery.SPServices-2014.01.js and jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js) and put the script in content editor. It didnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

The `.search()` function in Nadeem's answer was not working for me somehow :(

So I extended Nadeem's script to check if the user is there in  a particular group using [jQuery.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) and using [sputility.js](http://sputility.codeplex.com/documentation) hide the field by using `GetSPFieldByInternalName()` and `Hide()` methods of `SPutility.js`

```
<script src="/sites/.../Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/sites/.../Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/sites/.../Style%20Library/Scripts/sputility.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function ()
{


    $().SPServices(
    {
        operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
        userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
        async: false,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status)
        {
            var uName=$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser();
            console.log('UserName is '+uName);

            var xml = xData.responseXML;

            if ($(xml).find('Group[Name="UserGroup One"]').length<=0)

            {
            console.log('User is not in UserGroup One  group ');


                SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('New_x0020_Text_x0020_field0').Hide();


            }
            else{

            console.log('User is in UserGroup One group ');

            }
        }
    }
    );
}
);
```

In case, you want to only make the field as ReadOnly then you can use `SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName().MakeReadOnly()`

Answer (score 0):

create three view for the List and defined the Target Audiance for the user group.and when user will login show him only the respective navigation link that would be also defined based on target audiance.